# Sending data to stdin of another process through linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, bash, pipe

I've been trying to send data to stdin of a running process. Here is what I do:

1. In a terminal I've started a c++ program that simply reads a string and prints it. Code excerpt:

   ```
   while (true) {
       cin >> s;
       cout << "I've just read " << s << endl;
   }
   ```
2. I get the PID of the running program
3. I go to `/proc/PID/fd/`
4. I execute `echo text > 0`

Result: `text` appears in the terminal where the program is run. Note, not `I've just read text`, but simply `text`.
What am I doing wrong and what should I do to get this thing to print `'I've just read text'`?

Comment: How do you execute program from the shell? Do you run it as a background process?

Comment: No, I just run in in the foreground. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're starting your C++ program you need to make sure its input comes from a pipe but not from a terminal. You may use `cat | myapp` to do that. Once it's running you may use PID of your application for `echo text > /proc/PID/fd/0`

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of `stdout` not being properly flushed -- see "[Unix Buffering](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering)". Or you could be in a different shell as some commentators have suggested.

Generally, it's more reliable to handle basic interprocess communication via FIFOs or NODs -- named pipes.  (Or alternatively redirect `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a file and read from that with your `c++` program.)

Here's some good resources on how to use those in both the terminal and `c++`.

"[FIFO – Named pipes: mkfifo, mknod](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/fifo-named-pipes-mkfifo-mknod/)"
"[Using Pipes in Linux Processes](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/using-pipes-in-linux-processes/)"
"[Programming with FIFO: mkfifo(), mknod()](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/programming-with-fifo-mkfifo-mknod/)"

Comment: These are great, thank you. I tried using pipes, but decided to go as simple as possible and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

FD 0 is the terminal the program is running from. When you write to FD 0, you are writing to the terminal the program is running from. FD 0 is not required to be opened in read-only mode; in practice it seems to be read/write mode, so you can write to it. (I suspect this is because FDs 0, 1 and 2 all refer to the same file description)

So `echo text > /proc/PID/fd/0` just echoes `text` to the terminal.

To pipe input to the program, you would need to write to the other end of the pipe (actually a PTY, which mostly behaves like a pair of pipes). Most likely, whatever terminal emulator you're using (xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal) will have the other end open, so you could try writing to that.